# Traverse through unknown complex object dynamically using reflection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, system.reflection

I need to traverse through complex object using reflection. Only thing is it could be any type of object. Because of that, the property names are not known before hand.

The ultimate goal is to log this whole thing into string for logging purpose.

I have below code. But problem is , it doesn't reach to child level

```
public static string GetLogFor(object target)
{
    var builder = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var property in @target.GetType().GetProperties())
    {

        builder
            .Append(property.Name)
            .Append(" = ")
            .Append(property.GetValue(@target, null))
            .AppendLine();
    }

    return builder.ToString();
}
```

[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446093/logging-state-of-object-getting-all-its-property-values-as-string)

Comment: why not just defer this to a tool like a JSON serializer; it'll be done it 30 seconds, it'll be much more efficient than anything you come up with, and it'll work reliably; `var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(target);` done! plus is will be easy to consume that data later, if you need to; otherwise, the answer is "recurse the object graph, detect common collection types, etc"

Comment: @MarcGravell If I go for that option. Is there better way to format the `json ` into readable format in the logs.

Comment: check out `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(target, Formatting.Indented);` for better formatting

Comment: Thanks heaps guys, @MarcGravell  Can you please add this as a answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use `Json` serialization, if the output suits your logging needs:

```
public static string GetLogFor(object target)
{
    return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(target, Formatting.Indented);
}
```